# How to make custom local notifications patterns in iOS

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I would like to know if there is an API available to customise your vibration patterns. This is meant as when and IF the vibration should occur.

So what i basically want to achieve, is a pattern where a LocalNotification get's called and only by the first time of the day it vibrates with sound and vibration as default iOS standard. But then for the next time and forthcoming time on the same day it get's called so there is NO SOUND and NO VIBRATION.

This pattern will then be reset every day at 00:00 - which makes room for one notification with sound and vibration.

Is this possible programmatically?